# ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed

Tags: spring, initialization

I am new please help me where the exact problem is.

```
ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dataAccessContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not init listeners
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

It has happened the same error, then I realized it happens when I change the structure of the database and update the JPA annotations manually, and was a detail that escaped me, to solve what I did was create again all mappings of entities automatically (this I did with NetBeans wizard) and problem solved.

Also [this article](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/04/06/migrating-to-spring-3-1-and-hibernate-4-1/) has detailed instruction on Spring 3.1 and Hibernate 4.1 integration